# Video width & height is not refreshing in ES6 class

Tags: ecmascript-6, html5-canvas, html5-video, es6-promise, es6-class

I'm trying to set dimensions for canvas, based on my video dimensions. For some reason my video height and width is always 0. I assume it is something to do with my class which is not updating the details.

**Webcam.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Get User Media Code Along!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="photobooth">

    <canvas class="photo"></canvas>
    <video class="player"></video>
  </div>

  <script src="./webcam.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**webcam.js**

```
class Webcam {

    constructor(){
        this.video = document.querySelector('.player');
        this.canvas = document.querySelector('.photo');
        this.canvasContext = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.strip = document.querySelector('.strip');
        this.snap = document.querySelector('.snap');
    }

    captureVideo(){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
        .then(browserVideoStream => {
            console.log(browserVideoStream);
            this.video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(browserVideoStream);
            this.video.play();
        }).then(video => {
            this.videoToCanvas();
        })
        .catch(err => alert(err));
    }

   videoToCanvas(){
    let videoWidth = this.video.videoWidth;
    let videoheight = this.video.videoHeight;
    console.log(`${videoWidth} - ${videoheight}`); // THIS IS ALWAYS 0,0
   }

}

video = new Webcam();
video.captureVideo();
video.videoToCanvas();
```

Comment: I think you need a `return` for `return this.video.play();`? Otherwise you're reading the size before the video has started playing and thus before it knows the size.

Comment: thanks.. return is the culprit...

Answer (score 1):

`.play()` can take time, so you'll need to change

```
this.video.play();
```

to

```
return this.video.play();
```

so that the following `.then` handler waits for the video starts playing before calling `.videoToCanvas()`.

Comment: Correct but there should also be a note about the deprecation of `video.src = URL.createObjectURL(MediaStream);`. The correct way is `video.srcObject = MediaStream;` (which still requires waiting for the `loadedmetadata` event, or the fullfillement of `play()`'s returned Promise in supported browsers (only chrome and FF today)).